# AngularJS ng:repeat not working

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am working on a project in which I am integrating WooCommerce APIs
in the mobile application using AngualrJS.

Here is [the API](http://www.ilexsquare.com/JwelTech/wordpress/api.php?function=GetProductsdetails) which returns a list of products, and this is the HTML page on which I am implementing AngualrJS.

The problem is I am unable to display multiple products on the HTML page.

**HTML code:**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="productCtrl"> 
    <ul>
        <li>hello</li>
        <li ng:repeat="item in data">
            {{item.id}}  has children:  
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JS file:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('productCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://www.ilexsquare.com/JwelTech/wordpress/api.php?function=GetProductsdetails")
    .then(function (response) {$scope.data = response.data;});      
});
```

and this is my jsfiddle code
[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sabaShaikh/8kpyy6mw/)

Answer (score 5):

Just change your `ng-repeat` like this: `<li ng-repeat="item in data.products">`

Your products are under the key `products` in your `data`. See the working code below.

```js
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('productCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
      $http.get("http://www.ilexsquare.com/JwelTech/wordpress/api.php?function=GetProductsdetails")
        .then(function(response) {
          $scope.data = response.data;
        });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="productCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li>hello</li>
    <li ng-repeat="item in data.products">
      {{item.id}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) .. you saved my life :D

Comment: Sure, feel free to accept the answer so that others should not be coming in for the help :-)